# Mechanism of Supersymmetry Breaking (F-term, D-Term, Mediated)

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry

I will make my question clear.

SUSY is broken symmetry because we haven't seen superpartners. As far as I know, there are two mechanism of SUSY breaking, F-term and D-Term. 
Besides, there are some theories of messenger from hidden sector to visible sector, then induced Electroweak Symmetry Breaking (EWSB).

I am still confuse of these concepts of SUSY breaking.

What is the chronology/steps of SUSY breaking?

Thank you

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, of course we should consider if there is no SUSY at all. I have edited my question. I want to know what is the steps of SUSY breaking. Does SUSY breaking at hidden sector happen first or not.

Comment: Does it happen before what? All the effects that can break supersymmetry happen at the same time. There is no propagation delay between symmetry breaking terms.

Comment: A nice answer can be found at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24581